# Calculating a total value until a button is clicked

Tags: java, swing

I have created a pizza ordering program which has option for pizza base and pizza toppings.But this program has provision for ordering only one pizza at a time and the amount is generated for that particular pizza alone.how can i make this program with the logic that the customer can order pizzas until the (view amount) button is clicked and the total amount for all the pizzas bought are displayed in the textfield.
then the cycle repeats for another customer.
Is there a better method do tell me.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;


class p1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

JLabel l,l1;
JTextField t1;
JButton b1,b2,b3;
JRadioButton R1,R2;
Font f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6;
JCheckBox c1,c2,c3,c4;
int Tomato=10;
int Capsicum=15;
int Onion=20;
int Paneer=30;
int Soft=30;
int Hard=40;



    p1(String q)
    {   
    super(q);
    Container cc=getContentPane();
    cc.setLayout(null);
    f1=new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.PLAIN,16);
    l=new JLabel("SELECT BASE");
    cc.add(l);
    l.setFont(f1);
    l.setBounds(130,50,150,50);

    R1=new JRadioButton("SOFT--Rs.30");
    cc.add(R1);
    R1.setBounds(140,100,200,50);
    R1.addActionListener(this);
    R1.setSelected(false);

         R2=new JRadioButton("HARD--Rs.40");
    cc.add(R2);
    R2.setBounds(140,150,200,50);
    R2.addActionListener(this);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(R1);
    group.add(R2);

    f2=new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.PLAIN,16);
    l1=new JLabel("SELECT TOPPINGS");
    cc.add(l1);
    l1.setFont(f2);
    l1.setBounds(430,50,150,50);

    c1=new JCheckBox("Tomato-Rs.10");
    cc.add(c1);
    f3=new Font("Arial",1,15);
    c1.setFont(f3);
    c1.setBounds(440,100,300,50);
    c1.addActionListener(this);

    c2=new JCheckBox("Capsicum-Rs.15");
    cc.add(c2);
    f4=new Font("Arial",1,15);
    c2.setFont(f4);
    c2.setBounds(440,145,300,50);
    c2.addActionListener(this);

    c3=new JCheckBox("Onion-Rs.20");
    cc.add(c3);
    f5=new Font("Arial",1,15);
    c3.setFont(f5);
    c3.setBounds(440,190,300,50);
    c3.addActionListener(this);

    c4=new JCheckBox("Paneer-Rs.30");
    cc.add(c4);
    f6=new Font("Arial",1,15);
    c4.setFont(f6);
    c4.setBounds(440,235,300,50);
    c4.addActionListener(this);

    b1=new JButton("EXIT");
    cc.add(b1);
    b1.setBounds(550,350,70,30);
    b1.addActionListener(this);

    b2=new JButton("VIEW AMOUNT");
    cc.add(b2);
    b2.setBounds(50,350,150,30);
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    t1=new JTextField();
    cc.add(t1);
    t1.setBounds(50,300,70,30);


    b3=new JButton("PAY BILL");
    cc.add(b3);
    b3.setBounds(300,350,150,30);
    b3.addActionListener(this);


    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t)
{   
    int total=0;
    int toppingCost=0;
    int baseCost=0;

    if(t.getSource()==b3)
    {

    }


    if(R1.isSelected())

        baseCost+=Soft;

    if(R2.isSelected())

        baseCost+=Hard;

     if (c1.isSelected())

        toppingCost +=Tomato ;

    if (c2.isSelected())
         toppingCost += Capsicum;

    if (c3.isSelected())
        toppingCost += Onion;


    if (c4.isSelected())

        toppingCost += Paneer;

    total=baseCost+toppingCost;

    if(t.getSource()==b1)
        {

        this.setVisible(false);
        }

    if(t.getSource()==b2)
        {

        t1.setText("Rs:"+toString().valueOf(total));
        t1.setEditable(false);

        }

    }
   }

class pizzabase
{
public static void main(String args[])

{
    p1 obj=new p1("PIZZA HOUSE");
    obj.setSize(700,450);
    obj.setVisible(true);
    obj.setLocation(200,200);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a while loop?

Comment: the problem is that the amount for each is generated based on selection.the customer can order many pizzas until he views the total bill.i think while loop will not suffice.can you suggest exactly where to use it based on your point of view.

Comment: Something like: `while(!payBillPressed){...}`, where `payBillPressed` is a `volatile boolean` instance variable of `p1` (or whatever class contains your logic). Pressing the button triggers an **event** that starts a different thread. Triggering this event would then set `payBillPressed` to true.